# Passing S3 bucket location in Python Script to Luanch EMR cluster

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, markerclusterer

I Have a python script to launch an EMR cluster. In my script I try to pass S3 file location which is with application configurations in json format. I tried all possible ways, but I'm not able to pass the s3 locations. I am getting the following error.

> Invalid type for parameter Configurations, value: s3://test-cis-client-prod-development/emr/emr_configuration.json, type: , valid types: ,

How can I pass the json file location from s3 to my script?

Comment: Can you post your code on how you pass this JSON object?

Comment: What makes you think that a reference to a configuration in S3 is valid? Can you show us your code and a reference to the documentation that mentions using S3?